# How to change one object to another with animations

Tags: animation

is it possible to replace an object  with another?Lets say I have a character who can transform.They go from one form to another,I want to do that.Change one object to another without deleting the older object and its animations.Is it possible?

Comment: Watch the first minute or one and-a-half of this video to see if it results in what you want or what's acceptable to you. https://youtu.be/EI1RE1DPdd0 (Someone else's tutorial, odd method, might be your answer)

Comment: Does the armature need to change too? If the armature is the same (the way the bones are layed out for the character) then transforming the mesh and keeping the animations would be quite simple if I understand what you are asking.